# Archiving project on Xcode fails

Tags: xcode

I am getting the message

> The identity 'iPhone Developer: Rxx Pxxx (xxx)' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains

Can the problem be that I am logging for a coumputer of a diffrent user?, and if it is the problem, is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the private key and the certificate to go along with it.  You can export these from the computer they are on through Xcode's organiser window.